# How can I burn a .bin file to a flash drive and a floppy?

Tags: images, flash

I'm looking for a small free utility **without UI** for burning a .bin file to a flash drive. I need floppy support too but I don't care to use another tool for that (again, no UI, just command line).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS do you want it for?

Comment: Microsoft Windows

Comment: Note that the bin file in plain binary - it dosen't have any CUE/ISO/etc signature

Answer (score 2):

[`dd`](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) can do all that.

Comment: dd (both on unix and the windows version of it, cat, cp, ....  (E.g. `cat demofile.bin > /dev/fd0h1440`)...